# Alternate to hard coding this

Tags: javascript, excel, powershell, active-directory

I am writing a program to automate recording process, node → powershell → excel-sheet.
It sort of works for now, with little to no formatting of data (which is also a problem that I am unsure of how to solve), but the main problem is that I have hard coded a large portion into it (refer to ADPropertiesFunction.mjs).

Sample Data:

```
user 1 → (Name: User1), (Group: ['LoggedInViaOidcSso', 'bitbucket-users', 'jira-system-administrators'])
user 2 → (Name: User2), (Group: ['Group not found in hardcode', 'bitbucket-users', 'jira-software-user'])
user 3 → (Name: User3), (Group: ['Guests', 'Domain Admins', 'jira-system-administrators'])
user 4 → (Name: User4), (Group: ['LoggedInViaOidcSso', 'bitbucket-users', 'Schema Admins'])
user 5 → (Name: User5), (Group: [])
```

Code/Files Used:

ADPropertiesFunction.mjs

```
import { exec, execSync } from 'child_process';
import { promisify } from 'util';

var userList;
var userGroupList;

const searchUsers = () => {
    try {
        console.log("Running searchUsers.ps1...");
        const commandForFinding = `./searchUsers.ps1`;
        var usersName = execSync(
            commandForFinding,
            { shell: "powershell.exe" }
        )
        var arr = usersName.toString().split(/\r\n/);
        var len = arr.length;
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
            arr[i] && arr.push(arr[i]);
        arr.splice(0, len);
        var results = arr.map(element => {
            return element.trim();
        });
        results.splice(0, 2);
        userList = results;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}

const searchUserGroup = (Username) => {
    var commandForFindingGroup = `./FindADUserGroup.ps1 ${Username}`;
    var Group = execSync(
        commandForFindingGroup,
        { shell: "powershell.exe" }
    )
    var results = [];
    userGroupList = "";
    var arr = Group.toString().split(/\r\n/);
    var len = arr.length;
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
        arr[i] && arr.push(arr[i]);
    arr.splice(0, len);
    results = arr.map(element => {
        return element.trim();
    });
    results.splice(0, 2);
    // userGroupList = results
    if (results.length != 0) {
        if (results.includes("bitbucket-users"))
            userGroupList += "Bitbucket User"
        if (results.includes("confluence-users"))
            userGroupList += " Confluence User"
        if (results.includes("LoggedInViaOidcSso"))
            userGroupList += ""
        if (results.includes("jira-software-users"))
            userGroupList += " Jira User"
        if (results.includes("jira-servicedesk-users"))
            userGroupList += " Jira Service Desk User"
        if (results.includes("Group Policy Creator Owners"))
            userGroupList += " Group Policy Creator Owners"
        if (results.includes("Domain Admins"))
            userGroupList += " Domain Admins"
        if (results.includes("Enterprise Admins"))
            userGroupList += " Enterprise Admins"
        if (results.includes("Schema Admins"))
            userGroupList += " Schema Admins"
        if (results.includes("Administrators"))
            userGroupList += " Administrators"
        if (results.includes("Guests"))
            userGroupList += " Guest"
        if (results.includes("Denied RODC Password Replication Group"))
            userGroupList += ""
        if (results.includes("confluence-administrators"))
            userGroupList += " Confluence Administrator"
        if (results.includes("bitbucket-system-administrators"))
            userGroupList += " Bitbucket System Administrator"
        if (results.includes("jira-system-administrators"))
            userGroupList += " Jira System Administrator"
    }
}

const SaveExcel = () => {
    var j = 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < userList.length; i++) {
        searchUserGroup(userList[i]);
        const commandForExcelCmd = `./ADPropertiesFunction.ps1 ${userList[i]} ${j} "${userGroupList}"`;
        execSync(
            commandForExcelCmd,
            { shell: "powershell.exe" }
        )
        console.log("./ADPropertiesFunction.ps1 " + userList[i] + " " + "\"" + userGroupList + "\"");
        j += 3;
    }
}

searchUsers();
SaveExcel();
```

ADPropertiesFunction.ps1

```
$ADusername = $args[0]
$identity = $args[1]
$group = $args[2]

# Importing Active Directory module into PowerShell session
import-module activedirectory

# Excel opening operation section
$ExcelObj = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
# $ExcelObj.visible = $true #To show Excel in foreground
$ExcelWorkBook = $ExcelObj.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\ADPropertiesVer1\testADpropertiesVer1.xlsx")
$ExcelWorkSheet = $ExcelWorkBook.Sheets.Item("Sheet1")
$ExcelWorkSheet.Activate()

# Data processing section

$ADuserProp = Get-ADUser $ADusername -properties name, DistinguishedName | select-object name, DistinguishedName
$ExcelWorkSheet.Cells.Item($identity, 1) = $ADuserProp.name
$ExcelWorkSheet.Cells.Item($identity+1, 1) = $ADuserProp.DistinguishedName
$ExcelWorkSheet.Cells.Item($identity+2, 1) = $group

# Save the XLS file and close Excel

$ExcelObj.DisplayAlerts = $FALSE
$ExcelWorkBook.Save()
$ExcelWorkBook.close($true)
```

FindADUserGroup.ps1

```
$username = $args[0]
(Get-ADUser $username -Properties MemberOf).memberof | Get-ADGroup | Select-Object name
```

searchUsers.ps1

```
Get-ADUser -filter * | select-object name
```

From `ADPropertiesFunction.mjs`, you would have seen that the large portion of cross checking the users' identity is hardcoded onto the code. I found it is only possible to individually cross-check each group type, but for large scale, with a large groups pool, It is not practical to manually cross check each group's existence. Is there any simpler way to check group's existence without hardcoding a `if` check for each?

Also, regarding the formatting of the output. if the above problem is solvable in such a manner, where I am able to return-get each group as an string with an array, I can add the groups in excel, one for each column.

Even better, making the excel to give the look and feel of a "checklist" like:

```
Name|Admin|jira-user|bitbucketuser|bitbucketadmin|...
User1|1   |0        |1            |1             |...
User2|1   |0        |0            |1             |...
User3|1   |1        |1            |0             |...
.
.
.
```

Any assistance would be helping me a lot!

Comment: I'd do a separate json containing a map of the names / formatted names (eg: confluence-users -> Confulence Users). In the main script, you load the json content and just do a generic loop to go through the keys and if there is a membership that match the key, then you add its value to the `usergrouplist` variable. That way, your loop is not hardcoded anymore and whatever you change (add / remove things from the map), it doesn't impact that loop. Also, I suggested to use a separate json to store the map / dictionary so you don't edit the script when you have to change the map.

Comment: For the output, you can get the list of the possible groups in the order you want, then for each users, you add the name, then each groups as a new column with 1 / 0 . I won't post an answer since there is multiple questions in there but hopefully that will get you going. Since there is 2 different issues in there, I won't post an answer as I can't cover the js part as well I'd want.